# subset a data frame with dplyr and conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame such as :

```
   Groups   Name    names2  Category    value
    G1  A   habit1  cat1    20
    G1  A   habit2  NA  1
    G1  B   habit3  NA  100
    G1  B   habit4  cat3    23
    G2  A   habit5  cat4    32
    G2  C   habit6  NA  100
    G2  C   habit7  cat2    21
    G2  D   habit8  cat3    34
    G2  D   habit9  cat5    43
```

and I would like to only keep one row per `Groups` and per `Name`

and get :

```
Groups  Name    names2  Category    value
G1  A   habit1  cat1    20
G1  B   habit4  cat3    23
G2  A   habit5  cat4    32
G2  C   habit7  cat2    21
G2  D   habit9  cat5    43
```

where the row within `Group` an `Name` that wins is a row where there is an information in `names2` (not a `NA`) and if have information in all, the one that have the highest Value wins `(as G2-D vs G2-D)` 42 wins because `42 > 34`
If there is only `NA`, then keep the row with the best Value anyway.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you mean to keep the rows with Category not `NA`? All of your `names2` are none missing....

Answer (score 3):

What you need is `group_by` with `filter` and then `top_n`:

```
library(dplyr)

my.df %>% 
  group_by(Groups, Name) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Category)) %>% 
  top_n(1, value)

# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   Groups, Name [5]
#   Groups Name  names2 Category value
#   <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr>    <int>
# 1 G1     A     habit1 cat1        20
# 2 G1     B     habit4 cat3        23
# 3 G2     A     habit5 cat4        32
# 4 G2     C     habit7 cat2        21
# 5 G2     D     habit9 cat5        43
```

This however, will exclude groups where Category is missing for all entrys of that Name, Groups combination and if there are several maximum values it keeps all of them.

**Data**

```
my.df <- structure(list(Groups = c("G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2"), 
                        Name = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C", "D", "D"), 
                        names2 = c("habit1", "habit2", "habit3", "habit4", "habit5", "habit6", "habit7", "habit8", "habit9"), 
                        Category = c("cat1", NA, NA, "cat3", "cat4", NA, "cat2", "cat3", "cat5"), 
                        value = c(20L, 1L, 100L, 23L, 32L, 100L, 21L, 34L, 43L)), 
                   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```